# Async Ajax calls fails to get a response in Android

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

Am not able to get a response from Async Ajax calls in Android 4.2 devices. Everytime it gets timed out

```
xhr = $.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: url,
  async: true,
  contentType: "application/json",
  timeout : 20000
});
xhr.done(function(data, status, xhr) {//This never gets invoked.});
```

It always gets timed out. But if its `async : false` am able to get a response within 2s max.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug in Android WebView - [Async XMLHttpRequest in WebView always returns status 0](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42229).

Using `async:false` seems to be the only workaround.

More discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/RyId152tCaw).

Comment: Ok thanks for those links, but what confuses me is that I have 2 servers(one secured with basic HTTP auth) and it fails in secure server 90% of the time. But it does return response some time.